Can two processes both enter the busy wait under the Peterson's algorithm?
By looking at the Peterson's algorithm, the equivalent implementation in C++ is:
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
int main(){
  std::atomic<bool> flag[2] = {false,false};
  std::atomic<int> turn = {0};
  std::thread t1([&](){
     flag[0] = true;  // flag_set_0
     turn = 1;    // turn_set_0
     while(flag[1] && turn == 1){  // flag_read_0, turn_read_0
         //busy wait
     }
     // critical section
     flag[0] = false;
  });
  std::thread t2([&](){
     flag[1] = true;  // flag_set_1
     turn = 0;  // turn_set_1
     while(flag[0] && turn == 0){ // flag_read_1, turn_read_1
         //busy wait
     }
     // critical section
     flag[1] = false;
  });
  t1.join();
  t2.join();
}

In this program, if the execution order is:
flag[0] = true
turn = 1
flag[1] = true
while(flag[1] && turn == 1){} // true
turn = 0
while(flag[0] && turn == 0){} //true


The single total order is
flag_set_0 < turn_set_0 < flag_set_1 < flag_read_0 < turn_read_0 < turn_set_1 < flag_read_1 < turn_read_1,
which is a valid single total order without contradiction since it obeys the constraints required by t1 and t2:
t1: flag_set_0 < turn_set_0 < flag_read_0 < turn_read_0
t2: flag_set_1 < turn_set_1 < flag_read_1 < turn_read_1

This means the program can have both threads simultaneously enter the busy-wait loop and two infinite loops make the program unterminated, is my understanding right?

Yes, they can both enter their busy-wait loops.  Then one of them leaves, the one whose turn condition is false.  It's not a deadlock if that's what you're worried about.

@PeterCordes Then one of them leaves, the one whose turn condition is false. I meant both simultaneously enter the busy-wait loops, which would result in the program not being terminated because busy-wait has no operations such that the other existing loop. So, in this situation, how does one of them leave?

That's what I mean, that they're both inside their spin loops at the same time.  But one of them entered when turn was different, so on the next iteration its loop condition will be false.  The spin loops check both flag[other_thread] and turn every iteration, with opposite conditions for turn that can't be true for both loops indefinitely.  If you think a well-known algorithm that's been known for decades is broken, it's highly likely that you've made a mistake and should keep looking for a reason why it's not broken.

Why do you think those loops are infinite? They check some conditions in every iteration. Once these conditions changes, the loop is terminated.

@PeterCordes If both are inside their spin loop at the same time, how can turn be changed later? The change to flag is after the busy-wait exits, however, both are in busy-wait loops, how is the loop condition changed?

@PeterCordes Why do you think those loops are infinite? Because once two threads simultaneously enter the busy wait, the loop condition will never be changed. Once these conditions changes, the loop is terminated. When both threads enter the busy-loop, who changes the conditions?

@PeterCordes Oh, I see your meaning. It's my fault. Once the second thread enter the busy wait, its turn condition is mutually exclusive with the other, so the other must exit the loop in the next iteration.

You meant to reply to @DanielLangr with your second comment.  But anyway, turn is changed by the other thread, after one thread enters its loop, before the other thread enters its loop.  It's impossible for one thread to read turn == 0 and the other to read turn == 1 after both turn = assignments have executed, it's either one or the other.

@PeterCordes Yes, I see your meaning, the only possibility is that the implementation does not obey [atomics.order] p11(should within a reasonable amount of time), such that it always sees turn conform to the condition even if the other thread has changed it. But it is not the fault of the algorithm, it's the fault of the implementations, right? In this situation, all the operations in the condition would precede the change to the turn in the single total order S, right?

These are seq_cst operations so I'm not sure if even delayed visibility is possible after both loops have entered their spin loops.  Since that involves them both having read turn after writing it.  Maybe it's just an implementation detail that real hardware has to wait for a seq_cst store to become globally visible before a seq_cst load can read it, but if not, then the last turn= assignment is already visible to the other thread by the time the second thread enters its spinloop.  Maybe seq_cst requirements can still be satisfied without that happening in this case, though.

@PeterCordes In terms of the analysis in the question, the condition in the loop at best synchronizes with the flag set in the other thread, that is, there is no other requirement on what turn can read in the current thread from the other thread, we only know the set to the turn in the local thread happens before the load, so [intro.races] p18 applies, after the later thread enter the busy-wait loop, the next iteration of the former thread can still read the value of turn set in local...

... the single total order could be:flag_set_0 < turn_set_0 < flag_set_1 < flag_read_0 < turn_read_0 <(flag_read_0, turn_read_0, ... ) < turn_set_1 < flag_read_1 < turn_read_1 < (flag_read_1 < turn_read_1,...), which is still valid and do not violate other rules because single total order is irrelevant to the timeline, so it does not require the later happened load must read the prior store(in the timeline). IIUC, if the implementation does not obey the should suggestion, the result still can form a valid single total order.

In terms of a total order of all operations like you've shown with your execution order code block, you'd be appending reads of turn == 1 that have to come after turn = 1 if you want both threads to actually be spinning at the same time.  The whole point of SC-DRF is that programs execute as-if they ran in some interleaving of source order, although I guess the "as-if" gives some flexibility.  But it's hard to argue that both threads have truly entered the loop and done multiple iterations while both were in the loop.

Sure one can enter first and spin some iterations, then the other enters and spins some iterations waiting for the first thread to run its critical section, potentially for a while if the first thread was blocked.  But they weren't both spinning at the same time, at most one of them is stalled or descheduled so the second one to enter has to spin for a while.

@PeterCordes Anyway, from the perspective of the C++ standard, the two threads can keep spinning even if the memory order is seq_cst as long as the formed single total order does not violate any other requirements, and in this example, it seems there are no other extra requirements on the single total order, so two threads keep spinning is theoretically possible?

For both threads to keep spinning, you need one thread to keep reading turn == 0 and the other to keep reading turn == 1.  With both spinning, those reads would need to interleave with each other in the total order, which means they can't both keep seeing different values because the turn= stores are also part of that total order.  Each spin iteration involves a seq_cst load from turn.  I don't think it's meaningful to say a whole bunch of loads happen in one thread before it does the actual spinning, so it has multiple stale turn results to get through.

(There's my lease favourite word, again, "stale".  Another sign that we're not talking about reality anymore.)

@PeterCordes  «With both spinning, those reads would need to interleave with each other in the total order, which means they can't both keep seeing different values because the turn= stores are also part of that total order.» The total order is irrelevant to the program execution in the timeline. Each condition in their thread sees the locally stored turn and the load to flag that is stored on the other hand thread does not impose the synchronization of turn stored in the other...

(i.e. no happens-before relationship between the local condition and the modification to turn in the other thread). flag_set_0 < turn_set_0 < flag_set_1 < flag_read_0 < turn_read_0 <(flag_read_0, turn_read_0, ... ) < turn_set_1 < flag_read_1 < turn_read_1 < (flag_read_1 < turn_read_1,...) this is a valid single total order for the case where both threads keep spinning. Unless I missed something that would impose the requirement on that the condition in one thread must read the last modification to turn in the other thread.

Moreover, we have discussed in the other question that the total order does not grow incrementally as the program runs, it just includes the past and future X where X in this case means all seq_cst operations. So, why do they need "those reads would need to interleave with each other in the total order" Except that we find the requirement that the condition in one thread must strongly happens before the other condition in another thread or must read the turn written in another thread.

We've never discussed the seq_cst total order across all seq_cst operations before.  Only modification orders of individual objects.  Time is not irrelevant to the total order; the whole point of sequential consistency is that there aren't any (visible) reordering effects, just interleaving of program-order.  Unless you're mixing in acq_rel or weaker operations in a way that defeats the SC-DRF guarantee, it is meaningful to talk about how the operations interleave.  I don't find it convincing to say both threads are spinning when all the loads from one thread are before any from the other.

@PeterCordes «all the loads from one thread are before any from the other.» before in the single total order does not mean they must execute in such an order in the program execution. [atomics.order] p6 witnesses this point. Regardless of modification order and single total order, they're all total order, total order is irrelevant to timeline.

@PeterCordes The formation of the single total is completely defined in [atomics.order] p4, for operations to different atomic objects, the order is determined by strongly happen before, and for operations to the same atomic object, the order is also regulated by coherence-order before. The operations interleave in terms of the program don't contribute to either strongly happen before or coherence-order before. Unless we find out the requirement from such two points that imposes how operations in these two conditions must be ordered in the single total order.

Yes, they can both enter.  But one of them entered when turn was different, before the last store to it.  On the next iteration its loop condition will be false.  This isn't a deadlock.
The spin loops check both flag[other_thread] and turn every iteration, with opposite conditions for turn that can't be true for both loops indefinitely.

Yes, I see your meaning, the only possibility is that the implementation does not obey [atomics.order] p11(should within a reasonable amount of time), such that it always sees turn conform to the condition even if the other thread has changed it. But it is not the fault of the algorithm, it's the fault of the implementations, right? In this situation, all the operations in the condition would precede the change to the turn in the single total order S, right?

These are seq_cst operations so I'm not sure if even delayed visibility is possible after both loops have entered their spin loops. That involves them both having read turn after writing it.
Maybe it's just an implementation detail that real hardware has to wait for a seq_cst store to become globally visible before a seq_cst load can reload it (or actually for all previous seq_cst stores to become visible).  But if not, then the last turn= assignment is already visible to the other thread by the time the second thread enters its spin-loop. Maybe no seq_cst requirements would be violated if both threads read opposite turn values for multiple iterations in this case; if so, then yes only the "should" visibility promptness requirements prevent a deadlock.

If you think a well-known algorithm that's been known for decades is broken, it's highly likely that you've made a mistake and should keep looking for a reason why it's not broken.  (Or if you need to ask for help understanding it, at least phrase your question with the assumption that the algorithm is correct.  e.g. "How does Peterson's algorithm avoid a deadlock with both threads entering the spin loops?"  Phrasing it that way might prompt you to look at the loop conditions again, or not.)
